# Evaluate list of functions at a certain point

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a list of functions (actually they are derivatives) of the type:

```
{D[g[x,y],x],D[g[x,y],y]}
```

I would like to evaluate all of these functions at a point, say,[0,0], creating a list of the type:

```
{D[g[x,y],x][0,0],D[g[x,y],y][0,0]}
```

Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you want `D[g[x,y],x][0,0]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get what you *asked for*, you can use

```
dl = {D[g[x, y], x], D[g[x, y], y]};
Through @ dl[0, 0]
```

[image]

However, as noted by @Kuba, you probably *want*  something like

```
ClearAll[foo];
foo = Through@(Function[{x, y}, #] & /@ dl)@## &;
foo[0, 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly it. Thanks.

Comment: @user191919, my pleasure..

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := x^2;
g[x_] := x^3;

{f[#], g[#]} & @ 5
```

(*
{25, 125}
*)

Or for your example:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y;
g[x_, y_] := Sin[x] + y^3;

{D[f[x, y], x], D[g[x, y], y]} /. {x -> 3, y -> 4}
```

(*
{6, 48}
*)